# C++ convert int and string to char*

Tags: c++, string, char

This is a little hard I can't figure it out.

I have an int and a string that I need to store it as a char*, the int must be in hex

i.e.

```
int a = 31;
string str = "a number";
```

I need to put both separate by a tab into a char*.

Output should be like this:

```
1F      a number
```

Comment: Note: I don't need to print it in that format. I can do that. I have a function that takes a char* as a parameter. I need to convert it so I can use it for that function

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With appropriate includes:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
```

Something like this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << a << '\t' << str << '\n';
```

Copy the result from:

```
oss.str().c_str()
```

Note that the result of `c_str` is a temporary(!) `const char*` so if your function takes `char *` you will need to allocate a mutable copy somewhere. (Perhaps copy it to a `std::vector<char>`.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int myInt = 31;
const char* myString = "a number";
std::string stdString = "a number";

char myString[100];

// from const char*
sprintf(myString, "%x\t%s", myInt, myString);

// from std::string   :)
sprintf(myString, "%x\t%s", myInt, stdString.c_str());
```

Comment: Start with a `std::string`, not a `const char *`.

Comment: Any modern C++ compiler that allows linking to the C-runtime will compile this code (Jacob's code is Windows-centric but still works on that platform).  I've personally always loathed the overloaded << operators in the C++ I/O libraries, but I guess to each his own.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char display_string[200];
sprintf(display_string,"%X\t%s",a,str.c_str());
```

I've used [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) to format your number as a hexadecimal.

Comment: Requirements were to separate by a tab, not a space.

Comment: I don't think that warrants a downvote since the hardest part isn't including a tab :-/

Comment: 1) sprintf_s is not standard - 2) this is the C way to do that

Comment: Well, the OP wants to use a `char*`, hence `sprintf` isn't *so* unwarranted!

Comment: Jacob's updated the answer to use `sprintf`.  And since when were using C library functions illegal in C++ code?

Comment: @Kristo: I agree, especially since I still find formatting using iostreams to be much more painful to read (or even get right in the first place).  However, I think using `snprintf()` should be considered over `sprintf()`.

Comment: Yes, using C functions in C++ is often a lot easier. Regardless as to whether its "good practice" or not... whatever that means.

Comment: next time, tell everyone to not use "const" in fonction parameters, because "it's easier" and "it's not illegal". People like you are a real pain on SO. Every single day I'm reading such nonsense here. Won't you let the experts alone, instead of adding noise to this website ?

Comment: -1 for the buffer of length 200. It's either way too big (if we take the `str` given in the question), or not big enough (if `str` is of unknown length).

Comment: I would expect the OP to adjust the buffer length to his own needs. Or dynamically calculate it - which is probably  overkill.

Answer (score 1):

`str.c_str()` will return a null-terminated C-string.

Note: not answering the main question since your comment indicated it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

those who write "const char* myString = "a number";"
are just lousy programmers. Being not able to get the C basics - they rush into C++ and start speaking about the things they just don't understand.

"const char *" type is a pointer.
"a number" - is array. You mix pointers and arrays. Yes, C++ compilers sometimes allow duct typing. But you must also understand - if you do duct typing not understanding where your "ductivity" is - all your program is just a duct tape.